# Embed (Private Account) Instagram Videos on Tumblr

Tags: instagram

I keep my Instagram account set to private but I'd like to share my videos to my Tumblr account too. I know if I turn off account privacy and make my account public the videos will show up automatically but I'd like to keep some of the stuff hidden from public eyes.

What's odd is the pictures show up just fine but not the videos. They show up as content not available. Here is the code.

```
<div class="entry-content video-iframe">
    <iframe src="//instagram.com/p/8IzraHmXG0xDUmux5PwmB17OTTmuR8Ir3jVIQ0/embed/" width="700" height="812" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" kwframeid="2"></iframe>
        <div class="caption">
              <p>Pastor Myron gets it in.  (at Bridge Church Omaha)</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your code? you have to show us your workings so far.

Comment: Thanks! I added it.

Comment: I don't think anyone can fix this. This is an issue with Instagram and how they handle private content.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.